# CiviCRM database

Tags: database

I had a previous install of CiviCRM that was connected to a database that had to be changed for Wordpress site. Now, setting up CiviCRM again, I discover (in civicrm.settings.php) CiviCRM and the website are using two different databases. The CiviCRM tables are not in the site database. Is that an issue going forward, can I use separate databases? I do want to use Member Sync, which seemed to have worked, but did not add the correct Contact Sub-Type. What will happen if I change the database in the civicrm.settings.php file?

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Scarlett using two different Database would be the best practice and you don't have to worry about it.

If your Member Sync is not updating the correct Contact Sub type then you need to check why it is not doing so. this has nothing to do with two different database

I hope this helps !!!

Thanks